# Solving A Second Order Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: calculus

Given the equation $y'=5x^2+2y^2-7$, where $y(0)=-2$, find $y'(0)$.

So I'm sure you have to manipulate the equation to integrate both sides, solve for the constant, then use that to find what $y'(0)$, but I'm having trouble doing this, could anyone help me out?  Thanks

Comment: Please create a new question instead of editing your old one.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'(0) = 5(0)^2 + 2(y(0))^2 - 7$$

Comment: wow I was overcomplicating things thanks!

Comment: No problem! This would technically be a first-order DE by the way :-)